# Return a value from SQL Query Qt

Tags: sql, qt

I am trying to return a value from SQL Query. When logging in, 'Type' is a value in the database, 1,2 or 3.    username and password are QStrings in the code.

In my attempt, this returns the wrong value (just a 1)

```
int userrole = roleQry.exec("SELECT Type FROM [tss_people] WHERE Username=\'" + username + "' AND Password='" + password + "'");

       qDebug() << userrole;
```

Comment: (1) What do you expect to get? (2) This code is an open invitation to SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

`QSqlQuery::exec()` returns a status, i.e. whether the query was successfully executed or not.

Results can be optained by iterating over the query

```
while(roleQry.next()) {
    qDebug() << roleQry.value(0).toInt();
}
```